# Instance in public subnet but cfn-init fails over VPC endpoint from private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

let's keep it simple.

I have a **3 PublicSubnet** and **3 PrivateSubnet**. There's a bastion host, just one, assigned to a one of the public subnets. Private subnets (all 3) are linked with CloudFormation VPC endpoint. Now the funny thing is that when I launch bastion stack and it tries to do some things over **cfn-init** it simply fails. It attempts to connect to an **IP** of an **ENI** that is linked to aforementioned VPC endpoint.

If I:

- get rid of said endpoint, bastion stacks up momentarily.
- add a **SecurityGroupIngress** entry for a sec-group of an endpoint that permits all ingress connection from a **CidrIp** being the cidr of the VPC, bastion stacks up momentarily.

Now! Why is that :|.
It does not make any sense. How in the world a route that goes over to an endpoint finds its way into a routing table linked with public subnet? Here's the route table for public subnets:

```
172.36.0.0/16   local   active
0.0.0.0/0       igw-?   active
```

And 3 distinct route tables for private subnets

```
172.36.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0 nat-1 nat-2 nat-3
pl-6ea54007 vpce-s3
```

(actually all 3 look the same, there's local for VPC and there are 3 nats hence nat-1 to nat-3, an endpoint here is for S3)

Once again, to reiterate:

1. bastion is associated with public subnet, having public IP and a route to **InternetGateway**
2. said VPCEndpoint is linked to private subnets (not public)

Any ideas?

LOGS,FILES etc.

UserData:

```
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum update -y
          yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap || true

          trap '/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 1 --stack ${AWS::StackName} --region ${AWS::Region} --resource Bastion' ERR

          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init --verbose \
            --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
            --resource Bastion \
            --region ${AWS::Region}

          sleep 1
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal \
            -e 0 \
            --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
            --resource Bastion \
            --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Logs from `/var/log/cfn-init.log`:

```
2020-10-02 05:18:43,957 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint https://cloudformation.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
2020-10-02 05:18:43,958 [DEBUG] Describing resource Bastion in stack bastion-stack
2020-10-02 05:19:43,958 [WARNING] Timeout of 60 seconds breached
2020-10-02 05:19:43,958 [ERROR] Client-side timeout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 162, in _retry
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/util.py", line 231, in _timeout
    raise TimeoutError("Execution did not succeed after %s seconds" % duration)
TimeoutError
2020-10-02 05:19:43,960 [DEBUG] Sleeping for 0.115700 seconds before retrying
```

Existing endoints:
[image]

Comment: If there are things unclear, let me know. Honestly I just wanted to get this out in the wild to get an attention. In the same time it's quite late too ;-)

Comment: Your `pl-6ea54007` route will be more specific, so it will always get picked. Not sure if this is what you are asking for?

Comment: What is in the User Data? What is in the cloud-init log file (`/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`)?

Comment: @Marcin this `pl-6ea54007` is for S3 route. In fact I do have 3 VPC endpoints (one of gateway and two of interface type) linked to either private route table or private subnets (in turn linked to those tables)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I posted logs above

Comment: Yes. But this "Private subnets (all 3) are linked with CloudFormation VPC endpoint." is not the case, as I explained in my answer. CFN endpoints are not associated with any subnet.

Comment: As per @Marcin's answer, the VPC Endpoint for CloudFormation is made accessible to the entire VPC. You have listed ways to make it work (configure the Security Group) -- is there a problem with doing that?

Comment: Ok, I get that :). Just look at comments below. I used to have different setup and that was not the case. We've repeated that cfn endpoint for each set of private subnets  (over to additional cidr) defined for each service we've had. Bastion did not have had this issue before. I can't understand that.

Answer (score 2):

> said VPCEndpoint is linked to private subnets (not public)

This is not the case for CloudFormation VPC endpoint. I think you are confusing [VPC gateway edpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) with [VPC interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-interface.html).

In your case, when you create `CloudFormation VPC endpoint` you are creating **VPC interface endpoint**, however, you are referring in your question to `pl-6ea54007` route which is for **VPC gateway endpoints** (probably S3).

So `pl-6ea54007` is for VPC gateway endpoint (S3 I guess), not for CloudFormation VPC endpoint. **Both endpoint types work differently**, and the interface endpoints do not create any routes in any route table. The interface endpoints have VPC scope. This means that any subnet (private, public) can use the CloudFormation VPC endpoint, including your bastion host.

Comment: I actually have 3 endpoints (answer above). One for CloudFormation, one for S3 and the last one for SecretsManager.

Comment: @kornicameister Could you then clarify what do you mean when you write "Now! Why is that :|. It does not make any sense."? For me it makes perfect sense and works exactly as expected.

Comment: I wonder why this happens now. We are actually trying to implement another setup fo networking. We've used to have each stack define own cidr block, subnets and enpdoints. But as you said, we've quickly stumbled onto inability to maintain dozens of distinct Cidr blocks and so on. Anyway, to the point, when that was done like that we did not have had this issue. Right now we have 3 shared private subnets and one place where endpoints for each service live and suddenly publicly placed EC2 tries to use an endpoint?

Comment: @kornicameister  "suddenly publicly placed EC2 tries to use an endpoint?" - which endpoint? CloudFormation endpoint?

Comment: @kornicameister CloudFromation is inteface endpoint, not gateway endpoint. Interface endpoint has VPC scope. Any subnet will connect to it, does not matter private or public.

Comment: is there a way to keep public subnet communiction not to go through endpoints?

Comment: @kornicameister  For your endpoint you can disable `Private DNS` which is on by default. This will break the link with the endpoint and bastion will use internet. But instances in private subnet will need to explicitly use private endpoint for the CFN, which will require changes to its code. I'm not aware of other way of doing this sadly.

Comment: ok, I think that makes it. Everything seems to working. I still don't understand why that was not the case where I had multiple subnets in the same VPC and interfaces endpoints were linked there.

Comment: Three is a nat involved. Private subnets routing shows 3 routes (I have updated answer above). Why is that relevant?

Comment: `The interface endpoints have VPC scope` was key for me.  I had a VPC interface endpoint defined in a separate private subnet, but it was affecting routing of an EC2 request in a public subnet because it was within the same VPC.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - the problem was the EC2 security group doesn't listed in the CF endpoint SGs access list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).